# How to send the Access Token in order to access AWS services - BEGINNER

Tags: facebook, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cognito, amazon-cognito-facebook

I followed the following [tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/facebook.html) and got the `facebook` login working. At the end it prints out the `accessToken` which is great.

```
FB.login(function (response) {

  // Check if the user logged in successfully.
  if (response.authResponse) {

    console.log('You are now logged in.');

    // Add the Facebook access token to the Cognito credentials login map.
    AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials({
      IdentityPoolId: 'IDENTITY_POOL_ID',
      Logins: {
        'graph.facebook.com': response.authResponse.accessToken
      }
    });

    // Obtain AWS credentials
    AWS.config.credentials.get(function(){
        // Access AWS resources here.
             console.log('Access Token is '+ AWS.config.credentials.identityId);
         var s3= new AWS.s3();

    });

  } else {
    console.log('There was a problem logging you in.');
  }

});
```

I believe that the following line of code `Logins: {
            'graph.facebook.com': response.authResponse.accessToken
          }` will register the `accessToken` in `Cognito`. Correct me if i am wrong.

My problem is, Should I save this `accessToken` and pass it when ever I am communicating with an `AWS` service (for example : `DynamoDB` write Item or else while adding a file to `S3`) ?

If so How can I do it ? (I have almost googled the entire web and found none on this)

** Note: I think the purpose of a `accessToken` is to add some security when the user request to access an `AWS` service. So in that case How can I use the `accessToken` to validate ?

Answer (score 0):

Once you give it to Cognito in a call to get some credentials, Cognito will registered it to, and will give back credentials scoped to, that authenticated identity.

Those credentials alone will map back to that token, so all you need to give to other AWS clients when accessing them is the credentials. That being said, once those credentials have expired, you will need to have the token still handy to get more for that authenticated identity. Cognito requires at least one token linked to an authenticated identity to get credentials for it.

Comment: Credentials means `region / app Id / secret key` etc? If so how can the credentials expire ?

Comment: Credentials as in the AWS credentials that AWS.config.credentials.get( returns (see http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/getting-credentials.html). The credentials Cognito returns are only valid for an hour.

Comment: So in case if i am going to access `DynamoDB` or `S3` I should pass what is given in the link posted above ? What if the credentials are expired will I be notified if so ? And how am I suppose to extend the expiry again ? (Sorry for all these questions, I am a newbie and I have been stuck with this issue for a week now)

Comment: The SDK gets credentials automagically for you as long as the token it has  is valid. The documentation for refreshing those is unique per provider, but yes, you will get an exception when it has expired.

Comment: So you mean that I must save `accessKeyId ` , `secretAccessKey ` and `sessionToken ` and then pass it when I try to access any AWS resoruce ? Can you also show me an example code where it has been done. Please ?

Comment: Once you set the AWS.config.credentials with the Credentials Provider, you do not need to do anything (until the credentials expire, as Jeff Bailey mentioned). This blog may help you in getting started - https://blogs.aws.amazon.com/javascript/post/TxTUNTVES4AL15/Authentication-in-the-Browser-with-Amazon-Cognito-and-Public-Identity-Providers